# How to re-write this to work on mysql

Tags: mysql

mysql does not recognize with command.  can some tell me how I could re-write the below query so that I can run it on mysql

```
with cookie_weights as (
  select 
    cookie,
    1.0 / count(1) as channel_weight
  from (
    select 
      cookie,
      unnest(channel_list)
    from cookie_channels
  )
)
select 
  channel, 
  sum(channel_weight)
from cookie_channels
join cookie_weights 
  using (channel)
group by 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subqueries.html) instead.

Try something like:

```
select 
  channel, 
  sum(select 
    cookie,
    1.0 / count(1) as channel_weight
  from (
    select 
      cookie,
      unnest(channel_list)
    from cookie_channels
  )
) as c) as sum
from cookie_channels
```

Comment: This does not work.  I do not think unnest is a MYSQL function.

Comment: @user6241931 this was not supposed to work, just gives you a suggestion on how to use `subqueries` as a substitute for `with`